# How do I pass parameters from managed app to native app in wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a managed wp8 app and a native app, I want that I can launch the native app from managed app and send some parametes to it.

I tried both LaunchUriAsync and Package.Launch, and then receive from OnActivated function.
But the parameters is always empty.

my code is here:

managed app:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("vistagame1:123"));

//IEnumerable<Package> apps = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();
//Package p = apps.FirstOrDefault((a) => a.Id.Name == "SsAtack");
//p.Launch("?content=1234&param2=test");
```

native app:

```
void SsAtack::OnActivated(CoreApplicationView^ applicationView,IActivatedEventArgs^args)
{
     switch (args->Kind)
     {
     case ActivationKind::Launch:
     {
        LaunchActivatedEventArgs^ args2 = (LaunchActivatedEventArgs^)(args);

        Platform::String^ s = args2->Arguments->ToString();
        if(s == "1")
        {
             //always empty here.
        }

    }
    break;
case ActivationKind::Search:
    {
        char a[] = "123";
    }
    break;
case ActivationKind::ShareTarget:
    {
        char a[] = "123";
    }
    break;
case ActivationKind::Protocol:
    {
        char a[] = "123";
    }
    break;
default:
    break;
}

HardwareButtons::BackPressed += ref new EventHandler<BackPressedEventArgs^>(this, &SsAtack::OnBackButtonPressed);   
CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Activate();
}
```